# creating a pandas DataFrame directly from results of request.get().content

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I already have the contents of a csv file stored in a variable `file_data` as a result of this:

```
file_data = requests.get(file_url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, stream=True).content
```

is there a way to convert it straight into a pandas DataFrame without having to save it to disk as csv and then read_csv() into a dataframe?

```
with open(zip_file_name, "wb") as ofile:
     ofile.write(file_data)
```

Comment: what about `from pandas.compat import StringIO`,  `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_data))` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `StringIO`:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_data))
```